# Use same android emulator every time

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have started a new emulator from 'launch new emulator' . But when I run another project later another emulator is getting loaded . Actually I wanted to use the same emulator itself.I there any option to reuse the same emulator and prevent new emulator being launched automatically.

Comment: according to your application version and type it will load different AVD. like if you are running 2.0 and your another app is google api related or  2.1,2.2,2.3. it will load different AVD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `Run` use `Run>Run Configurations>Target>Manual` and manually select the AVD that is already launched.

Answer (score 1):

I often have this problem when i both have the physical device( a real phone) plugged in the pc and an emulator. You can put the devices list near the console and logcat views, so you can select here the right device to use (install the app and show the logcat).

Go in window -> show view -> other -> devices.

From there you can select which device to use (if nothing is selected, a new emulator is run following the target option you set following Mangusto's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the emulator that you wish to make default from windows->android sdk manager->
edit the virtual device from that you can select skin you want. or set the dimension.
I think this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Run > Edit Configurations`, choose your run configuration on the left side, check `Use same device for future launches` checkbox.