# Android Development on Eclipse: Always opens new emulator

Tags: android

This should be a really simple one.  I am doing the Hello Android tutorial and I was able to get my app to install into the emulator.  However, when I go to run again (with no changes) the eclipse environment insists on launching a new emulator instead of connecting to the existing one.  How do I fix that?  My development environment is a Mac Mini running Mac OS 10.6.8.

Thanks.

New Update:

I have found the answer:

First I read this [question linked above by Mangusto][1]
[Use same android emulator everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136268/use-same-android-emulator-everytime/8136352#8136352)

Then I realized that what one really needs to do, if the emulator is opening and initializing slowly, is to start the emulator, wait for it to initialize, and then attach to it the manual way described in the link above.  Automatic does not work if your emulator is starting slowly as it disconnects as I described in the update below.

Thanks for the responses.

Update:

Below is the print out from eclipse (I tried to link image but could not due to my user level.  I need reputation level of 10 or more).  I had already tried the suggestion below about automatic vs manual.  I think the issue is that while the apk file was installed it did not automatically launch in the emulator.  Therefore, eclipse disconnected from the emulator.  I was able to see my application by navigating to the apps within the android emulator.
[2011-11-24 08:25:34 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'myAvd' based on Android 4.0, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor, 
[2011-11-24 08:25:34 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2011-11-24 08:25:34 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=240v
[2011-11-24 08:25:34 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=24
[2011-11-24 08:25:34 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512
[2011-11-24 08:29:17 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-11-24 08:29:17 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-11-24 08:29:17 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-24 08:29:17 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-11-24 08:29:17 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myAvd'
[2011-11-24 08:29:17 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myAvd'
[2011-11-24 08:29:25 - Emulator] 2011-11-24 08:29:25.377 emulator-arm[984:80b] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-11-24 08:29:25 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-11-24 08:29:25 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-11-24 08:31:29 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-24 08:31:29 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-24 08:31:29 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2011-11-24 08:33:36 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-11-24 08:33:36 - HelloAndroid] (null)
[2011-11-24 08:33:36 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554': Connection reset by peer
[2011-11-24 08:33:36 - HelloAndroid] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Connection reset by peer
[2011-11-24 08:33:36 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
[2011-11-24 08:34:55 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-11-24 08:34:55 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-11-24 08:34:55 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-24 08:34:55 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-11-24 08:34:55 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myAvd'
[2011-11-24 08:34:55 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myAvd'
[2011-11-24 08:35:03 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2011-11-24 08:35:05 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2011-11-24 08:35:06 - Emulator] 2011-11-24 08:35:06.756 emulator-arm[1004:80b] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-11-24 08:35:06 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2011-11-24 08:35:06 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-11-24 08:35:11 - HelloAndroid] emulator-5556 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
[2011-11-24 08:42:36 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-11-24 08:42:36 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-11-24 08:42:36 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-24 08:42:36 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-11-24 08:42:36 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'myAvd' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-11-24 08:42:36 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myAvd'

Comment: Check this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136268/use-same-android-emulator-everytime/8136352#8136352)

Answer (score 13):

Its because your `application Target` mode has set to `manual`. To solve :

```
Right Click on your project-> Run as -> Select Run Configurations ->
In that select Target Tab ->Select Automatic instead of manual
```

Click on `Apply` and `run`.

Now your app doesn't prompt for a device.

For a `reverse` case Select `Manual`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 this fixed my problem with Eclipse using an emulator even when my device was plugged in. Thanks yo.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **DDMS** Perspective and if you can't see any emulator device on the list, Find the  "View menu" **dropdown** on the "Devices" window on the left, and click **Reset ADB**.

After adb restarted it should be able to show all of your devices again.

Answer (score 0):

Me also had the same problem.First of all clean your project.Take the DDMS mode in the eclipse .Here you are able to handle the devices in the emulator.There you can see the emulator control.From there select your device and run it.Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: O.k I had already tried what Udaykiran suggested to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had BlueStacks android app player installed. Its an application that runs on mac and pc allowing you to emulate android. Looks like it uses the android emulator under the covers. To uninstall on mac, go to Library>bluestacksplayer  and uninstall app ... .solved the emulator 5554 problem.