# Android: Multiple Emulators Launching for Same Project

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on an Android Project which is set to run on Android 4.0.3 (least version to support is 2.2).

Whenever I run the project, it launches a separate emulator each time even if an emulator is running. Each device takes so much time to start up. I tried changing the Run Configuration to "Always prompt to pick device" but the running emulator is not getting listed under the Active devices list.

Using Eclipse 3.7 with latest ADT and Android SDK on windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: do not set ur runing target to manual,u need to put it automatic follow this `Right Click on your project-> Run as -> Select Run Configurations ->
In that select Target Tab ->Select Automatic instead of manual` click apply & than run for more detail see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258434/android-development-on-eclipse-always-opens-new-emulator

Comment: Both goes the same way. When it is set to automatic, each time when I run the project that opens a separate emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a bit late but hope it may help someone who reaches here.

The issue was due to some connection problem between the ADB server and the running emulators. Restarting the server would fix the issue.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure an emulator for each 2.2 and 4.0.3 configuration. Then right click project --> Run As --> Run configurations --> Dialog box will open --> select Target tab --> check Manual in deployment Target selection mode.

If you do with manual, then you get to know which emulator is currently running and that emulator can be re-selected to run for same application.

Comment: I have 3 emulators configured but when one emulator is up and active and I run the project again (In manual mode) the "Android Device Chooser" window should show the running device under "Choose a running device" category. But in my case all devices are listed under "Launch a new Android device"

And when I select the same device again, it launches another emulator.

Comment: Now check you have only one application associated in Run As window.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what the actual problem was, But the problem disappeared when I reinstalled eclipse and ADT plugin and changed my workspace location to a new clean one.

Comment: Possibly issue with ADT plugin with installed eclipse version, anyways took a long route, but somehow you cleared up your problem, Good!!!